# nodejs storing the returned value of a function inside a variable gives me undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fs

Hello I have a function in nodejs that search for a specific word inside a file
I want the returned value of this function to be stored inside a variable to use it in a POST API for mongodb and mongoose
But it returns it as **undefined** for some reason

This is my **POST API** and the function **Filetostring()** inside it

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');
    
     function Filetostring(){ 
        
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
            arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {
            if(step.includes("step")){
            console.log(step);             //this gives me the first result I need

             return step;

            }

        
            }); 
     }
     let steps = Filetostring()
     console.log(steps) // This gives me undefined

    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        upload: req.files[0].filename ,
        
        run : steps, //this is where I want to put the returned value of the function
        
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    //const file = req.file;
    console.log(req.files[0].filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("error") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

This is a picture of my console and the result of each console log [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQGv0.png)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why the variable **steps** is giving me undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function `Filetostring`, `forEach` method does not return the value from the outer function call. When you write `return` in the `forEach` callback you just quit the callback execution but not returned the value from the `Filetostring` call.

Try this.

```
function Filetostring(){ 
    let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
    // Find returns the first element that matches our criteria
    const step = arr.find((step , idx)=> {
        if (step.includes("step")) {
         console.log(step);             //this gives me the first result I need

         return true;

        }
        return false;
     }); 
   
   return step;
 }
```

UPD: Based on the feedback in the comment. If you need to filter multiple items in the array and not the first one `filter` should do the trick.

```
function Filetostring(){ 
    let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
    // Filter returns elements that matche our criteria
    const steps = arr.filter((step , idx)=> {
        return step.includes("step");
     }); 
   
   return steps;
 }
```

Comment: This works thank you but it gives me just 1 line (only the first time it finds the word 'step').  when i want the function to find every line that has the word 'step' .. does arr.find() stop when it find the value searched for once?

Comment: Yes it is. If you need to find all steps use `filter` method. I will edit the answer for you.